# The unthinkable sequence

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

***To correctly answer this question, I would like you to include the next 5 numbers of this sequence and also tell me why they are the correct numbers.***


3, 4, 8, 9, 14, 23, 25, 31, 36, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?


***I will add hints if nobody gets it after a while.***

Comment: https://oeis.org/A046974 did you try this? "Partial sums of digits of decimal expansion of Pi."

Comment: @Oray yes. that is correct

Comment: It's such a nice sequence though; it's almost a shame that OEIS ruins it for us. By the way, in case you didn't find it yet, the tag wiki (click on the [tag:number-sequence] tag, and then "learn more") has a link to a [meta question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/number-sequence-puzzles-what-not-to-do) that gives (despite its unnecessarily negative point of view) some very good advice on creating number sequence puzzles that most people on this site would find interesting. Hope to see more puzzles from you soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence is 39,44, 52, 61, 68. as @oray told these are the Partial sums of digits of decimal expansion of Pi.